# Start only TOR without Firefox

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, windows, email, torbirdy

I have installed the tor-browser-package and I'd like to use tor only in combination with Thunderbird\torbirdy and without Firefox therefore I tried to start only tor.exe (I also tried tor.exe with some parameter (https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en)) but torbirdy seems not to work in this case. Is there a way to start only tor without the Firefox browser under Windows?

Comment: Strange, the tor packaged with tor-browser is a full blown tor binary and shouldn't be chained to tor-browser. Did your try `tor.exe --defaults-torrc [path to torrc]`? What errors does starting tor give? Or does it start properly without error and torbirdy just not work afterwords?

Comment: If I start tor.exe, the socks5 port seems to be 9050 instead of 9150.

Answer (score 6):

You can run tor.exe without Tor browser in this way:

1) Copy torrc.defaults into the directory in which tor.exe is
2) Open cmd prompt windows
3) chdir to the directory where tor.exe is
4) Execute cmd line: tor.exe -f .\torrc.defaults

You will see tor is running and Socks listening on port 9150, Control listening on port 9151.

Comment: Correct however in my installation it is torrc-defaults instead of torrc.defaults. Default directory if you are using Tor browser is: "~\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor".

Comment: For me, the working port is 9050. (proxy-server="socks=127.0.0.1:9150")